# How to add the points[4] to the contours by using opencv framework

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm currently using opencv framework(3.4.1) for object measuring, but I am not able to add `points[4]` to the contours. Please let me know how to add `points[4]` to the `boxContours` in the code below.

I can pass `boxContours` to the `drawContours` only if I add points to the former.

```
cv::findContours( gray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, 
CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
NSLog(@"contour size %lu",contours.size());
for (int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++)
{
    cv::RotatedRect rect = cv::minAreaRect(contours[i]);
    cv::Point2f points[4];
    rect.points(points);

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>> boxContours;

    cv::drawContours(image, boxContours, i,cvScalar(0,255,0),2);   
}
```

Comment: 1. create an empty std::vector<cv::Point2f> . 2. for each of your ponts: add it to that new vector 3. push back the new vector to your vector of vectors

Comment: drawContours doesnt work with cv::Point2f, you'll have to use a vector of vector of cv::Point instead

Answer (score 1):

Please see this code for Drawing Rotated rectangle! You can easily draw the Lines instead!

```
Mat image(200, 200, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0));
RotatedRect rRect = RotatedRect(Point2f(100,100), Size2f(100,50), 30);
Point2f vertices[4];
rRect.points(vertices);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    line(image, vertices[i], vertices[(i+1)%4], Scalar(0,255,0));

imshow("rectangles", image);
waitKey(0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

drawContours function needs a vector of vector of cv::Point, so you'll have to construct that, if you want to use that function. For example this way:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/coloredLines.png");

    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_8UC1);

    // create the edge mask:
    for (int j = 0; j < image.rows; ++j)
        for (int i = 0; i < image.cols; ++i)
            if (image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j, i) != cv::Vec3b(255, 255, 255)) mask.at<unsigned char>(j, i) = 255;


    // here's where your code starts:

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point > > contours;
    cv::findContours(mask, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);


    // now draw all the bounding rects, using  drawContours function:
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        cv::RotatedRect rect = cv::minAreaRect(contours[i]);
        cv::Point2f points[4];
        rect.points(points);

        // must be cv::Point to be used by drawContours function
        std::vector<cv::Point> boundingContour;

        // push all the contour points in that temporary vector
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
            boundingContour.push_back(points[j]);

        // create a temporary dummy container that could hold multiple contours, but we'll only have exactly one in here
        std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> boxContours;
        boxContours.push_back(boundingContour);

        // there is only 1 contour inside, so always draw the 0-index contour!
        cv::drawContours(image, boxContours, 0, cvScalar(0, 255, 0), 2);

    }

    cv::imshow("image", image);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

here are the images I used:

input:

[image]

used mask for findContours:

[image]

result:

[image]